# If $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=0$, then $\sum_n a_n$ converges iff $\sum_n b_n$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Suppose $a_n > 0$ and $b_n > 0$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$. Also, $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n/b_n = 0$. Then the sum of $a_n$ converges iff the sum of $b_n$ converges ...both from 1 to infinity.

My approach is that
$\lim a_n/b_n = 0$ means that there exists $N \in \Bbb N$ for which $|a_n/b_n - 0| < 0$ for all $n\ge N$. Then $0 < a_n < 0$. The sum of $a_n$ from $1$ to infinity is $0$. So The sum of $a_n$ from $1$ to infinity is convergent.

Is this proof that easy or I miss something?

Comment: This is a good conceptual start. Use the definition of limit convergence.

Comment: Are you sure about that "iff"? What if $a_n = \frac1{n^2}$ and $b_n = n^2$?

Answer (score 1):

Given that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=0,$ we know that there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>N$ we have $|\frac{a_n}{b_n}-0|<1$. That is, $\frac{a_n}{b_n}<1$ fo sufficiently large $n$. This tells us that $b_n$ eventually dominates $a_n$. Hence if $b_n$ converges, then $a_n$ also needs to converge. If $a_n$ diverges, then so does $b_n$.

Comment: This is a proof of what the question perhaps should be. As Lord Farin points out, the iff is too strong a statement it seems.